# macportsの導入について

Tags: macos

公式サイトからdmgでダウンロードした結果

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/shims:$PATH"
export PATH="/Users/k14044kk/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.3.1/envs/opencvtest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2.cpython-35m-darwin.so:$PATH”export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/Users/k14044kk/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/Users/k14044kk/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
 ##
 #Your previous /Users/k14044kk/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/k14044kk/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2017-06-03_at_14:33:49
 ##
 #MacPorts Installer addition on 2017-06-03_at_14:33:49: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"←１６行目
 #Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

#以降が追加されました。
ただ
`source ~/.bash_profile`を打つと

```
-bash: /Users/k14044kk/.bash_profile: line 16: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
-bash: /Users/k14044kk/.bash_profile: line 18: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

が返されます。どのように解決すればよろしいでしょうか？ちなみに１８行目はありません…。

Answer (score 0):

```
export PATH="/Users/k14044kk/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.3.1/envs/o‌​pencvtest/lib/python‌​3.5/site-packages/cv‌​2.cpython-35m-darwin‌​.so:$PATH”
```

のように`"`が`”`になっていました。
(質問のコードには当該部分の記載はありません)

Comment: 第三者にもわかるよう、何が問題でどう解決したのかを明記してください。

Comment: export PATH="/Users/k14044kk/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.3.1/envs/opencvtest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2.cpython-35m-darwin.so:$PATH”　　　”←この部分が不適当文字列だったので”→から"に変更したところ問題なく動作致しましたすみません。